# how to change this query to use join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, mariadb

```
SELECT breakgame, Streak,
((SELECT (maxGameId - gameId) as gameGap
FROM game_result
WHERE game_result.breakgame >= kokopam.game_streak.breakgame
ORDER BY gameId DESC LIMIT 1)/ Streak) as nowWeight
FROM kokopam.game_streak, (SELECT max(gameId) as maxGameId FROM game_result ORDER BY gameId DESC LIMIT 1) maxGameId
WHERE breakgame>= 2
```

how to change this query to use join?

please help me

Comment: Could you share table schema. I think this query will not compile.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `(SELECT max(gameId) as maxGameId FROM game_result ORDER BY gameId DESC LIMIT 1)` --> `(SELECT max(gameId) as maxGameId FROM game_result)`

Answer (score 0):

In first place, you should've a condition in the "where" clause that states the ID that the rows share.

Anyway, the method you're using works the same as inner join.

```
Select * 
From tableA a, tableB b
Where a.id=b.id
```

Is the same as

```
Select *
From tableA a
Inner join tableB b on b.id=a.id
```

I could help you a bit more if you specify what you were trying do in the query and the columns that the tables have.